# How to find the distances between tuples in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find the distance between the tuples in the list below.

```
_list=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

Below is my attempt and the error I got as output.

```
print [(x[1][-1]-x[0])for x in _list]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    [(x[1][-1]-x[0])for x in _list]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any suggestions on how to get around this? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write:

```
[x[1] for x in _list]
```

You'll get:

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

So when you're doing:

```
[(x[1][-1]-x[0])for x in _list]
   ↑
 an int
```

It's like writing `1[-1]` which make no sense and it's an error. You probably want:

```
print [(x[1] - x[0]) for x in _list]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, but there's a little problem. My expected result is `[1,1]` and not `[1,1,1]`. The first item on the list should not have been used in the subtraction.

Comment: `[(x[1] - x[0]) for x in _list][1:]`should do it then.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> _list=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> print [(x[1]-x[0])for x in _list]
[1, 1, 1]
```

**Whats wrong** in your code

```
print [(x[1][-1]-x[0])for x in _list]
              ^ Not required
```

Which was similar to writing

```
>>> 100[-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you mean that you wanted the distances between the elements of the tuples, not the distance between tuples. I do like the other answers and it's always good to exercise with list comprehensions.

Just two things:
If you want to vectorise (potentially speed up) the operation and
if you'd like the result to be an actual distance (result of a norm) then use `map` and `numpy.linalg.norm`:

```
import numpy as np    
_list = [(1, 2) ,(3, 4), (5, 6)]
distances = distancesmap(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x[0]-x[1]), _list)
print distances
Out[5]: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```